# c# code the system give me error but i dont know why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
((e.Values("NewsOn")))= DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

> Error 1   Non-invocable member
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs.Values' cannot
>   be used like a method.    c:\Users\test\documents\visual studio
>   2012\WebSites\WebSite4\My website\addNews.aspx.cs 12  13  WebSite4

Answer (score 1):

You've used **( )** instead of **[ ]**. Try this:

```
((e.Values["NewsOn"]))= DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says  you can't use the Values Property like a method. My guess is that it is an indexer and you should use square brackets:
`((e.Value["NewsOn"]))= DateTime.Now.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think all of the parentheses make it harder to read. Try the following:

```
e.Values["NewsOn"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```